# Excel VBA: Auto-changing my line breaks in odd way? Should I be placing these differently?

Tags: excel, vba

Excel VBA, Office 2016.  I have a few long lines of code and I'd like to break them up before or after the Or/And operators.  However, when I do this VBA moves them to weird places after I move off of the line.  (I apologize if I'm doing this wrong or if it is stupid question, new to coding and to stack)

Here is what I enter:

```
Sub testhere()
If [Table1].Cells(1, [Table1[Referral Type]].Column).Value = "T" Or _
   [Table1].Cells(1, [Table1[Referral Type]].Column).Value = "TE" Then
        MsgBox ("OK")
```

Here is what Excel VBA changes it to:

```
Sub testhere()
If [Table1].Cells(1, [Table1[Referral Type]].Column).Value = "T" Or [Table1 _
   ].Cells(1, [Table1[Referral Type]].Column).Value = "TE" Then
    MsgBox ("OK")
```

That seems like such an odd place to put the line continuation.  Anyone know how to avoid this?

Comment: Honestly its a clunky `If/Or` - you could really clean this up with `Select Case`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  It isn't that clunky, but I'm trying to make the code as readable as possible for whoever comes after me.  I'll look at that if no one knows why VBA is auto-adjusting my breaks!

Comment: The "clunky" was more in reference to all the brackets, i.e. using [Table1] instead of a `ListObject`, or `ListColumn` variable maybe. `Select Case` would make this much more readable if you keep the brackets.

Answer (score 0):

Taking this question in a slightly different direction and avoiding line continuation entirely, you could use:

1. `Select Case` - simplifies the `IF/OR`.

---

```
Sub Test1()
    Select Case [Table1].Cells(1, [Table1[Referral Type]].Column).Value
        Case "T", "TE"
            MsgBox "OK" ' Note that you don't need parentheses around "OK"
    End Select
End Sub
```

---

2. Or perhaps use `ListObject` and `ListColumn` variables instead of referring to `[Table1]` and `[Referral Type]`

---

```
Sub Test2()
    Dim myTable As ListObject
    Dim referralTypeCol As ListColumn

    Set myTable = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Table1")
    Set referralTypeCol = myTable.ListColumns("Referral Type")

    Select Case referralTypeCol.DataBodyRange.Cells(1).Value
        Case "T", "TE"
            MsgBox "OK"
    End Select
End Sub
```